# Django: debug AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: django, django-models

NOTE: I finally found the bug, so the below text was valuable perhaps only to me. The short answer: I decided to create a model field out of an attribute I had earlier defined as a `@property-method`. The only place where I hadn't removed the `@property-method` was in the Orchid model.

---

After some tweaked and poking to my code, I suddenly get this error: `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. I haven't changed any of the code for `Orchid`, but I now get this error:

```
>>> orc = Orchid.objects.get(id=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/cole/PycharmProjects/Sites/virtualenvs/orchidislandcapital.com/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cole/PycharmProjects/Sites/virtualenvs/orchidislandcapital.com/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Users/cole/PycharmProjects/Sites/virtualenvs/orchidislandcapital.com/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/cole/PycharmProjects/Sites/virtualenvs/orchidislandcapital.com/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Users/cole/PycharmProjects/Sites/virtualenvs/orchidislandcapital.com/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 230, in iterator
    obj = model(*row_data)
  File "/Users/cole/PycharmProjects/Sites/virtualenvs/orchidislandcapital.com/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 347, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.attname, val)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

The definition for Orchid is `class Orchid(FinancialReturnMixin, PeerPerformance)`. I haven't changed the `FinancialReturnMixin`, whose code is:

```
class FinancialReturnMixin(models.Model):
    exclude_special_dividend = True
    round_to = 4

    shares_outstanding = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    stock_price = models.FloatField(
        verbose_name='quarter-end stock price',
        blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        app_label = 'snippets'
```

The second part of the `Orchid` class definition is `PeerPerformance` from which I have commented out the one change I had made. The definition for `PeerPerformance` is `class PeerPerformance(DividendBookValueMixin)` and all I did here was add 1 additional field to the model. `DividendBookValueMixin` is an abstract model.

I deleted my Orchid migrations, datatable and relevant south_migrationhistory entries. With `class Orchid(models.Model)`, the Orchid model sets up fine. With `class Orchid(PeerPerformance)` the Orchid error remains. All my tests against `PeerPerformance` run. I can read and save `PeerPerformance` objects just fine.

```
>>> from peer.models import PeerPerformance as PP
>>> pp1 = PP.objects.get(id=1)
>>> pp1.dividend = 0.135
>>> pp1.save()
```

`DividendBookValueMixin` is the parent class for `PeerPerformance`. With `class Orchid(DividendBookValueMixin)` the error remains. All my tests agains `DividendBookValueMixin` run.

Any thoughts where to look?

Comment: If you have the solution, please answer your own question and accept that. I came here, saw no accepted answer, and very nearly navigated away without seeing your edit - which was exactly the cause of my issue (but in a parent class).

Answer (score 0):

(On linux)Sometime this occurs when you don't have read write permissions to the project directory or in virtualenv directory. Make sure you have apropriate read write permissions to the directory.